# Wordpress CST Quiz plugin leaderboard to show team scores?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a trivia quiz on wordpress and trying to create a leaderboard that shows the scores for each team of users in addition to an overall weekly / monthly leaderboard.

The quizzes are built using the WP CST Quiz plugin, and the weekly and monthly leaderboards were generated using [rkcstQuizLeaderboardweekly] and [rkcstQuizLeaderboardmonthly] (before I joined the project so I'm not sure how).

My users are split into three groups and I'd like to show the rankings within each group as well. Is there a shortcode I can use for this? Or how do I create one?

I can see the scores broken down by team view in the WP CST Quiz / Manage Quiz Result tab in the admin view so I know the plugin can do this, but I don't know how to display this same information on a user-facing page.

Right now, I have a blank leaderboard for each team that was created using WP Pro Quiz, but it isn't able to pull in data from the quizzes built in the other plugin.

Is there a plugin or combination of plugins that I can use to build quizzes that can sort data like this? If not, what should I do to try and build something that will do the job?